# arduino + adafruit cc3000 connect to network

Tags: network-programming, arduino

I have one arduino and one module wifi adafruit cc3000,  I'm researching about this equipment and I want a web page to control a led(on/off).

I was researching on google and found this tutorial that helped me a lot:
http://www.openhomeautomation.net/wireless-relay-arduino-wifi/

But that works localhost and i want access this in any network i'm conected, anyone can help me or give me advices than i want' to do?

Answer (score 0):

These might help, they are ways of connecting to the arduino from the web.
http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2014/03/20/homecaster-using-the-adafruit-wifi-shield-to-send-messages-from-the-web-to-arduino-cc3000-iot/

http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2014/01/13/ardustat-web-controlled-wireless-arduino-based-thermostat-featuring-adafruit-cc3000-arduino/

http://bitknitting.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/test-send-data-from-arduino-to-a-web-server/

You could also telnet into the arduino via the internet and customise this program to be a controller.

https://github.com/plotly/arduino-api/blob/master/plotly_streaming_cc3000/Adafruit_CC3000/examples/ChatServer/ChatServer.ino